# Tap and move on 2 dimensions

Tags: android

I need to create a window that the user can tap. I need to know when the user starts tapping, stops tapping, if the user moves his finger keeping it down, and the exact coordinates of where he taps, and where he is moving his finger, in real time.
I cannot understand which widget is the best for this kind of activity: can someone give me a hint, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `View` (including any `ViewGroup`) with an attached `OnTouchListener` can do what you're looking for. In the `ACTION_DOWN` event, you can record where the tap occurred; in the `ACTION_MOVE` event, you can get the coordinate of the current pointer location.

Simply attach an `OnTouchListener` to your view and handle it accordingly:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                float xTap = event.getX();
                float yTap = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float xMovement = event.getX();
                float yMovement = event.getY();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I needed this simple hint.